# newly installed mysql configurations for php

Tags: php, mysql

usually i used to download and install xampp or wamp, but this time i tried setting up `apache24`, `php` individually.

Well apache and php is working fine, except i want to install mysql.

i downloaded and installed mysql 64bit MSI installer from this below link

```
http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/mysql/
```

but after that i dont know what to do with that because i can not connect do database, what is database username password etc etc..

i tried to lookup over internet, i found i have to do some changes in my.ini, but i dont have my.ini, instead i have my-default.ini, so i put values of port directory etc.

If anyone can direct me to right path or give me link, what is the best way to configure mysql with step by step instruction.

**my-default.ini**

```
# For advice on how to change settings please see
# http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/server-configuration-defaults.html
# *** DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE. It's a template which will be copied to the
# *** default location during install, and will be replaced if you
# *** upgrade to a newer version of MySQL.

[mysqld]

# Remove leading # and set to the amount of RAM for the most important data
# cache in MySQL. Start at 70% of total RAM for dedicated server, else 10%.
# innodb_buffer_pool_size = 128M

# Remove leading # to turn on a very important data integrity option: logging
# changes to the binary log between backups.
# log_bin

# These are commonly set, remove the # and set as required.
basedir = C:/mysql/
datadir = C:/mysql/data
port = 3306
# server_id = .....


# Remove leading # to set options mainly useful for reporting servers.
# The server defaults are faster for transactions and fast SELECTs.
# Adjust sizes as needed, experiment to find the optimal values.
# join_buffer_size = 128M
# sort_buffer_size = 2M
# read_rnd_buffer_size = 2M 

sql_mode=NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION,STRICT_TRANS_TABLES
```

Comment: I strongly suggest you try [MySQL Installer](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/windows/installer/) instead. In any case, search for "reset mysql password" in your favourite search engine.

Comment: What is your current problem ? MySQL is running ? I guess that default values should be port `3306` and username `root` without password.

Comment: @Debflav
Yes for xampp or wamp you are right, but after installing mysql individually not using xampp or wamp, isnt there any file i have to apply changes too? cuz i cant connect with the settings you gave, i have already tried those settings

Comment: You can't login as root? You have no old mysql services running?